# Why delegate is not calling on navigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know how to use delegate pattern

1. declare protocol
2. required or optional method
3. `id<> delegate` property
4. `[delegate respondtoselector:@selector(method)]`
5. inheriting protocol in `class <someProtocol>`
6. `-(void) protolcolMethod`
7. `class1Obj.delegate = self;`

I am using this several place in my app, but now i am doing this again in same app respondtoselector is not working. The only difference is this time its in NavController.

NavController parent tableview class didselectrow, push another view, which has button on which calls presentmadelcontroller and this is where i declared my protocol and inherited in navigationContoller parent class. **But why its not working**? I am struggling this for several hours.

*This class is presented modally and declare this protocol*

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@protocol xPro <NSObject>
-(void)xGet;
@end

id<xPro> xDel;

@interface rosterForGroup : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSArray *dispName;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<xPro> xDel; 

- (IBAction)xFunc:(id)sender;

@end


.m file ...
- (IBAction)xFunc:(id)sender
{
    [xDel xGet];
}
```

*And this class is NavController Parent class*

```
    ...
    @interface groupChatViewController : UIViewController<XMPPRoomDelegate, createNewGroupDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, xPro>
    ...
    @property (strong, nonatomic) rosterForGroup *xR4G;
    ...


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    xR4G = [[rosterForGroup alloc]init];
    xR4G.xDel = self;
...

-(void)xGet
{
    NSLog(@"AAAAAAH");
}
```

Please avoid these strange objects name.

*rosterforgroup alloc/init*

```
- (IBAction)openGroupOptions:(id)sender
{
     roster4Group = [[rosterForGroup alloc]init];
     [roster4Group setDelegate:self];
     [self presentModalViewController:roster4Group animated:true];
     //[xmppRoom fetchMembersList]; 
}
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a question somewhere in there?

Comment: What's the value of xDel at the time you call [xDel xGet];?

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry i didn't get your question.

Comment: You have your delegate variable `id<xPro> xDel;` just floating out there. Shouldn't that be an ivar?

Comment: is `rosterForGroup` laid out in a storyboard, or a xib file?

Comment: Insert `NSLog(@"xDel: %@", xDel);` before `[xDel xGet];`.  What does it print?

Comment: RobertRyan, its a @property (strong, nonatomic) id<xPro> xDel;

Comment: xDel: (null) ..... but why ? :(

Comment: OK, change that log to `NSLog(@"rosterForGroup: %@", self);` and add `NSLog(@"rosterForGroup: %@", xR4G);` just before `xR4G.xDel = self;`.  If the addresses are different, you have your answer: two different controller objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a long-shot; but I suspect that the rosterForGroup which is actually "on screen" is *not* the same instance that you are `alloc/init`ing in your viewDidLoad method. Perhaps you are getting there via segues or some other method; but the code you show does not indicate (though it could be in the code you omitted) that you are actually setting up your xR4G view controller as a *contained* View Controller and putting it on screen (after hooking up it's action methods, etc.

This means that the solution is a slight re-structuring of your View Controller relationships, which may merit an additional SO question if it's not clear to you how to accomplish that (this question, as it stands, isn't the right place to advise on how to get what you want).

## edit

I also suspect that your `rosterForGroup` View Controller is not being properly initialized. Simply doing an alloc/init on a VC will not properly setup it's views and their IB* Connections (unless it's `loadView` method does it all programmatically). They should either be loaded out of your storyboard or a XIB file (`initWithNibName:` or `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`

Comment: thanks for reply.. give me 5 mins let me paste the alloc init codes

Comment: - (IBAction)openGroupOptions:(id)sender {
    
    
    roster4Group = [[rosterForGroup alloc]init];
    
    [roster4Group setDelegate:self];
     
    [self presentModalViewController:roster4Group animated:true];
    
    //[xmppRoom fetchMembersList];
    
}

Comment: rosterforgroup has only initwithnibname no other init method.

Comment: Ah, please edit your original question with that! It's good details :-)